# Immediate shut down when try to change something in storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm building a tutorial app (Calculator) and when I try to change something in the Storyboard file it immediately crashes. It doesn't matter if i change the background color or the font size it just crashes ..

I have tried to 
1.clean the project 
2.repair disk permission
3.create a new project

nothing helps

> Application Specific Information:
>   ProductBuildVersion: 4G2008a
>   ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-1930/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:651
>   Details:  Failed to arbitrate IBNSLayoutConstraint, IBUIButton, IBUILabel, IBUIView, and IBUIViewController.

Comment: what ios version are you building for?

Comment: Im building on the standart Xcode IOS SDK 6.0

Comment: what version of xcode do you have? have you tried reinstalling latest Xcode?

Comment: 4.5.2 (4G2008a) is my Xcode version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unchecking "Use Autolayout" in the "File Inspector" of the Storyboard. Worked for folks in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12915560/1354100).